# Java Initialization/Declaration of Objects

Tags: java, object, initialization

I have an object, obj, of type MyObject, that I declare an instance of.

```
MyObject obj;
```

However, I don't initialize it. MyObject's Class looks something like:

```
public class MyObject {
    public String i;
    public String j;
    public MyObject(String i) {
        i = this.i;
    }
}
```

So now, I want to set the value of j. So I say:

```
obj.j = "Hello";
```

Can I do this without having initialized obj? i.e. without saying:

```
obj = new MyObject("My i");
```

Will this object be null if I were to check the value of it, if I don't initialize it, or is setting a field within it enough to make it not null?

Thanks!

Comment: Your constructor statement is backwards. It should say `this.i = i;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. You will have to create a new instance of `MyObject` if you want to access its fields.

Unless you make the fields `static`, ofcourse.

Do note that having your fields `public` violates encapsulation. You should make them private (or `protected`, if it's appropriate) and use getters and setters to provide access.

Sidenote:

```
public MyObject(String i) {
    i = this.i;
}
```

This will not do what you want.

You have to assign the parameter `i` to the field variable `i`, not the other way around.

```
public MyObject(String i) {
    this.i = i;
}
```